# Switching the language directly in the application

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Have been trying to localize my app into 7 languages, but all tutorials that I found only display how to on a single page, not through out the app.

I am now at the point where the localization works when device is of that language, but need to have ability to change languages via button.

EDIT: The below code works fine for anyone looking for a similar solution.

Notes about below:

1. The below groups of code create an in app language change, including the tab bar names.
2. You MUST put all data in the localize.strings as the main.strings will NOT work with this.  That means you will need to programmatically add all "back", "cancel" and navigation titles, as well as menu items.
3. The NSNotificationCenter inside each of the "changeToXX" func is set to notify the tabBarViewController (or any controller you need) that the language has changed.

i

```
import UIKit 
let AppLanguageKey = "AppLanguage"

let AppLanguageDefaultValue = ""

var appLanguage: String {

get {
    if let language = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(AppLanguageKey) {
        return language
    } else {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(AppLanguageDefaultValue, forKey: AppLanguageKey)
        return AppLanguageDefaultValue
    }
}

 set(value) {
     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue((value), forKey: AppLanguageKey)
 } 

 }

 let languageChangedKey = "languageChanged"

 class SettingsLanguageVC: UIViewController
 {


    @IBOutlet weak var languageENButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagENImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageENTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkmarkEN: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var languageDEButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagDEImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageDETitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkmarkDE: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var languageFRButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagFRImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageFRTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkmarkFR: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var languageESButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagESImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageESTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkmarkES: UIImageView!

    var tabBar = TabBarController()
    var MyDelegateClass = ""


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureView()
        print(appLanguage)

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back".localized, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(SettingsLanguageVC.back(_:)))
        navigationItem.title = "Select a language".localized

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func setTranslatedText(){
        if appLanguage == "es" {
            checkmarkShowES()

        } else if appLanguage == "de" {
            checkmarkShowDE()

        } else if appLanguage == "fr" {
            checkmarkShowFR()

        } else {
            checkmarkShowEN()
        }

    }
    func configureView(){


        let localeEN = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
        let English = localeEN.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "en")

        languageENTitleLabel.text = English
        flagENImageView.image = UIImage(named: "flag-en.png")
        languageENButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeToEN), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        //German

        let localeDE = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "de")
        let German = localeDE.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "de")

        languageDETitleLabel.text = German
        flagDEImageView.image = UIImage(named: "flag-de.png")
        languageDEButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeToDE), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        //French

        let localeFR = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr")
        let French = localeFR.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "fr")

        languageFRTitleLabel.text = French
        flagFRImageView.image = UIImage(named: "flag-fr.png")
        languageFRButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeToFR), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        //Spanish

        let localeES = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es")
        let Spanish = localeES.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "es")

        languageESTitleLabel.text = Spanish
        flagESImageView.image = UIImage(named: "flag-es.png")
        languageESButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeToES), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


        if appLanguage == "es" {
            checkmarkShowES()

        } else if appLanguage == "de" {
            checkmarkShowDE()

        } else if appLanguage == "fr" {
            checkmarkShowFR()

        } else {
            checkmarkShowEN()
        }
    }


    func changeToEN(sender: UIButton)
    {
        checkmarkShowEN()
        appLanguage = "en"
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(languageChangedKey, object: self)
        [self.viewDidLoad()]
    }

    func changeToDE(sender: UIButton)
    {
        appLanguage = "de"
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(languageChangedKey, object: self)
        [self.viewDidLoad()]
    }

    func changeToFR(sender: UIButton)
    {
        checkmarkShowFR()
        appLanguage = "fr"
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(languageChangedKey, object: self)
        [self.viewDidLoad()]
    }

    func changeToES(sender: UIButton)
    {
        checkmarkShowES()
        appLanguage = "es"
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(languageChangedKey, object: self)
        [self.viewDidLoad()]
    }


    func checkmarkShowEN (){
        self.checkmarkEN.hidden = false
        self.checkmarkDE.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkFR.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkES.hidden = true
    }


    func checkmarkShowDE (){
        self.checkmarkEN.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkDE.hidden = false
        self.checkmarkFR.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkES.hidden = true
    }

    func checkmarkShowFR (){
        self.checkmarkEN.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkDE.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkFR.hidden = false
        self.checkmarkES.hidden = true
    }

    func checkmarkShowES () {

        self.checkmarkEN.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkDE.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkFR.hidden = true
        self.checkmarkES.hidden = false
    }



    @IBAction func back (sender: AnyObject) {
        //back one VC
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }


}
```

All text needing to be localized, need to have the suffix .localized, along with the following inside StringExtension.swift

```
    extension String {

var localized: String {
    return localized(appLanguage)
}

var localizeStringUsingSystemLang: String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
}

func localized(lang:String?) -> String {

    if let lang = lang {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(lang, ofType: "lproj") {
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path)
            return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
        }
    }

return localizeStringUsingSystemLang
}
}
 return localizeStringUsingSystemLang
    }
}
```

Here is the TabBarController code:

1. Note:  The tabs "search", "Favorites" and "More" are system tabs.  I had to change them to custom and manually add the names to the tabs and add my own icons.  Otherwise the they would not be localized.

   import UIKit

   class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       setTabViewControllerParams(0, tabBarItemTitle: "Species".localized, navigationItemTitle: filterBy)
       setTabViewControllerParams(1, tabBarItemTitle: "Regions".localized, navigationItemTitle: "My Regions".localized)
       setTabViewControllerParams(2, tabBarItemTitle: "Favorites".localized, navigationItemTitle: "Favorites".localized)
       setTabViewControllerParams(3, tabBarItemTitle: "Search".localized, navigationItemTitle: "")
       setTabViewControllerParams(4, tabBarItemTitle: "More".localized, navigationItemTitle: "Reef Life Apps")

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TabBarController.languageChangedTrigger), name: languageChangedKey, object: nil)

   }


   func languageChangedTrigger () {

       [self.viewDidLoad()]
   }


   func setTabViewControllerParams(index: Int, tabBarItemTitle: String, navigationItemTitle: String) {

       if let tabBarItems = tabBar.items {
           if index < tabBarItems.count {
               tabBarItems[index].title = tabBarItemTitle
           }
       }

       if let viewControllers = viewControllers {
           if index < viewControllers.count {
               if let navigationController = viewControllers[index] as? UINavigationController {
                   if navigationController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
                       let viewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0]
                       viewController.navigationItem.title = navigationItemTitle
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Lastly, I added the below to the AppDelegate's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" so that when a non English based phone launches, the app will launch in their language, rather than the default English.

```
if NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode)! as! String == "es"
{   appLanguage = "es"
}else if NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode)! as! String == "fr" {
    appLanguage = "fr"
}else if NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode)! as! String == "de" {
    appLanguage = "de"
}else  {
    appLanguage = "en"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello David! Tel me your aim. Do you want to create menu inside app, and change the language in any way? For example, if the primary system language is English, then you change it such as French. Or do you always want to load the language is the same as the system language?

Comment: Thanks, what I would like is for the app to run as the same as system language (done), but also allow the user to switch languages if needed. Open to ideas, but was thinking of a button over the language and when pressed, display an UIAlert to confirm selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

let AppLanguageKey = "AppLanguage"
let AppLanguageDefaultValue = "en"

var appLanguage: String {

get {
    if let language = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(AppLanguageKey) {
        return language
    } else {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(AppLanguageDefaultValue, forKey: AppLanguageKey)
        return AppLanguageDefaultValue
    }
}

set(value) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue((value), forKey: AppLanguageKey)
}

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSLog("title user lang: \("Title".localizeString)")
    NSLog("title En: \("Title".localizeString("en"))")
    NSLog("title Ru: \("Title".localizeString("ru"))")
    NSLog("title Fr: \("Title".localizeString("fr"))")
    NSLog("title ??: \("Title".localizeString("blabla"))")
    NSLog("title sysem lnag: \("Title".localizeStringUsingSystemLang)")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
}
```

> StringExtension.swift

```
import Foundation

extension String {

var localizeString: String {
    return localizeString(appLanguage)
}

var localizeStringUsingSystemLang: String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
}

func localizeString(lang:String?) -> String {

    if let lang = lang {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(lang, ofType: "lproj") {
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path)
            return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
        }
    }
    return localizeStringUsingSystemLang
}
}
```

> Localizable.strings (Russian)

```
"Title" = "Привет";
```

> Localizable.strings (English)

```
"Title" = "Hello";
```

> Localizable.strings (French)

```
"Title" = "Salut";
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't this only switch the language in the ViewController (based on the above example)?  If so, I need this to switch the entire app.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can't change NSLocale. But you can create your own function, which will get localised strings of the user language. Using  NSLog("title user lang: \("Title".localizeString)") you will load selected language string. This mechanism will work throughout the application.

Comment: Getting close now.  I added to the unbutton for each of the languages:  appLanguage = "en" and NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize().  Now the language updates as expected, but it does not refresh.  It only changes when leaving a vc and returning to it.  How to refresh all?

Comment: I added the code and used the [viewDidLoad] function to refresh.  While this is getting very picky, I noticed once last MINOR issue.  The current VC refreshes and all pages refresh as well when loading that VC.  However, when I hit the back button from this VC to the "settingsViewController" page, the "SettingsViewController" does not refresh.  I assume due to back button not forcing a refresh of the page.  Is it possible to refresh the "SettingViewController" as well?

Comment: Ok. You can update all text in textViews in viewWillAppear(_:) or viewDidAppear(_:)  functions in every view controller. This is another question, if you create new question, I will write new code example for you.

Comment: Thank you.  here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Vasily, I found one issue with the code and created another question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39242174/2920324