# Switching language in running app for view elements in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, localization, storyboard

I have an app that that I am wanting to change languages inside the app and this works fine with the localize.strings, but this code is not triggering the main.strings files.

The below is the code used in the settingsLanguageVC

```
import UIKit

let AppLanguageKey = "AppLanguage"
let AppLanguageDefaultValue = "en"

var appLanguage: String {

get {
    if let language = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(AppLanguageKey) {
        return language
    } else {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(AppLanguageDefaultValue, forKey: AppLanguageKey)
        return AppLanguageDefaultValue
    }
}

set(value) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue((value), forKey: AppLanguageKey)
}

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Here is the code used in the stringsExtenstion.swift

```
import Foundation

extension String {

var localizeString: String {
    return localizeString(appLanguage)
}

var localizeStringUsingSystemLang: String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
}

func localizeString(lang:String?) -> String {

    if let lang = lang {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(lang, ofType: "lproj") {
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path)
            return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
        }
    }
    return localizeStringUsingSystemLang
}
}
```

Comment: So, do you want to use different string files? Or, you use for example system button "done", and you want to translate system elements?

Comment: I would like to use both the main.strings (storyboard) and the localized.strings.  Currently, only the localized.strings are being inputed.  The main strings have the tab names, plus menu items on some of the tabs.  This is why I need both.  I tried adding the menu items to the localize.strings, but this did not work

Comment: I suggest you to set all titles of your view elements programmatically. After one hour I will make the sample for you.

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: OK, did that and it works great.  Now just need to localize navigation titles and tab names

Comment: Ok. So, do you need the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

> TabBarController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    setTabViewControllerParams(0, tabBarItemTitle: "ONE".localizeString, navigationItemTitle: "ONE".localizeString)
    setTabViewControllerParams(1, tabBarItemTitle: "TWO".localizeString, navigationItemTitle: "TWO".localizeString)
}

func setTabViewControllerParams(index: Int, tabBarItemTitle: String, navigationItemTitle: String) {

    if let tabBarItems = tabBar.items {
        if index < tabBarItems.count {
            tabBarItems[index].title = tabBarItemTitle
        }
    }

    if let viewControllers = viewControllers {
        if index < viewControllers.count {
            if let navigationController = viewControllers[index] as? UINavigationController {
                if navigationController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
                    let viewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0]
                    viewController.navigationItem.title = navigationItemTitle
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

> Localizable.strings (Russian)

```
"ONE" = "один";
"TWO" = "два";
```

> Localizable.strings (English)

```
"ONE" = "one";
"TWO" = "two";
```

> Localizable.strings (French)

```
"ONE" = "un";
"DEUX" = "deux";
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="nUR-Hp-pCa">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="CyN-qL-pwy">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="pYF-J2-lCH" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="7sj-ZO-H6Z"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="z8T-yS-yZZ"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="fUH-or-StF">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="t7h-zd-rWW"/>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="yti-8g-g3h" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1837" y="905"/>
    </scene>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="qSl-mU-Ice">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="6og-vK-uE7" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="8pT-ac-TqX"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xne-JP-NAW"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="cy0-Zm-dW4">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="Yme-f2-Ybt"/>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="sj3-Kd-b6r" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1837" y="244"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Tab Bar Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="hYk-it-5Yg">
        <objects>
            <tabBarController id="nUR-Hp-pCa" customClass="TabBarController" customModule="stackoverflow_39242174" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ZIu-fS-Ven">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="49"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </tabBar>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="9ZZ-tm-gKt" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="tba-rV-XaM"/>
                    <segue destination="QV0-6J-vKg" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="MnC-tA-o6W"/>
                </connections>
            </tabBarController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5R8-Ki-Qv1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="205" y="575"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Item 1-->
    <scene sceneID="5eX-TM-S1f">
        <objects>
            <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="9ZZ-tm-gKt" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Item 1" id="6fX-a0-rTY"/>
                <toolbarItems/>
                <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="LaV-6J-YLJ">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </navigationBar>
                <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="6og-vK-uE7" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="H4K-P1-t3E"/>
                </connections>
            </navigationController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="n57-4l-GAt" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1025" y="244"/>
    </scene>
    <!--Item 2-->
    <scene sceneID="nqO-69-Jkp">
        <objects>
            <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="QV0-6J-vKg" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Item 2" id="YyT-40-7qX"/>
                <toolbarItems/>
                <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="ukb-bm-c5h">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                </navigationBar>
                <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                <connections>
                    <segue destination="pYF-J2-lCH" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="gRY-up-TJA"/>
                </connections>
            </navigationController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="geq-VQ-SVO" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="1025" y="905"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Vasily,  I got it working, tab bar items and all.  Thank you for all of your support.  I will update the previous post with all code in case you want to see what i did.  Thanks (Can you give me an up vote for the three questions too?)

Comment: For any user seeing this post.  Please go here for all details and final code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201644/switching-the-language-directly-in-the-application